# Query parameters utm_source, utm_id etc are being stripped from the URL

Tags: laravel, url, utm-tracking

In my app, when I hit a URL which has utm_source param, the page gets redirected to the same link but with the UTM code removed as a parameter.

All other parameters go through fine.

So if I visit: [www.site.com?page=1](http://www.site.com?page=1) I end up on [www.site.com?page=1](http://www.site.com?page=1)

But if I visit: [www.site.com?page=1&utm_source=123](http://www.site.com?page=1&utm_source=123) I get redirected to [www.site.com?page=1](http://www.site.com?page=1) too, the utm code was stripped off

However, it does not strip out utm_id.

So [www.site.com?page=44&utm_source=test&utm_id=345](http://www.site.com?page=44&utm_source=test&utm_id=345) it only strips away the source, so end up on [www.site.com?page=44&utm_id=345](http://www.site.com?page=44&utm_id=345)

I have checked all my middleware and nothing seems to be looking at utm codes specifically.

This does not happen in Firefox, why is Chrome removing these params?

**Update: Ok, ok, this has been a big waste of time. The params are being removed by a privacy chrome extension I have installed**